Light Path: Is Shadow Ray Not working
The way I usually approach it isn't working.
I've followed numerous tutorials and read forums and the way I have it set up should work.
How to resolve this issue?


Translucent is a somewhat odd node, check to see if transparent is what you want

I just retried plugging transparent instead of translucent. This doesn't work either.

So, I went back a few versions of Blender to troubleshoot the issue, and that seems to have worked.

For anyone that has this issue (trying to hide the shadow of an object), in addition to using the above node setup, you gotta go into the Object panel and under Visibility, then Ray Visibility, uncheck "Shadow". You might not see it instantly, so either unplug and replug a Shader node or switch from another type of Shading back to Rendered Shading and that should work fine. I had to scour the internet to find this solution.

that would just make the object not emit shadows though?

I thought that was what OP was trying to achieve? I guess I misunderstood the question. I'll edit my answer.

Well the OP didn't specify what was the end goal so we can't tell for sure  What we do know is he wanted to make the Is Shadow Ray work. It could be used for many things, and one might as well give an answer for that, so that anyone trying to do any of the many things with it can understand how it works. Which is what I tried to do in my answer.

As Allen mentions, Translucent is probably not what you are looking for here.
Think of the translucent shader as a way to mimic the effect of light shining through the skin of your hand or of a lamp shade.
You probably want a Transparent shader (Or principled's Alpha) (here with a slightly gray color, otherwise the default pure white makes it fully transparent), or maybe even a glass shader (Or Principled's transmission):

So it's normal that your current node setup seems to not work, but it isn't the light path node that is at fault, it's the Translucent not making visible significance in that context.

The Mix shader mixes the first and last shader inputs by the factor from 0 to 1.
In your setup, see the "is shadow ray" returns 1 if it is a shadow ray, or zero. So in a case like this:

When a shadow ray hits the surface, the "is shadow ray" returns a value of 1, therefore the green Transparent is used. Otherwise, the blue Principled is used. This effectively affects only the shadow of your object.
If you invert the inputs, you get this:

The Principled is used for your shadows, while the Transparent is used for your non-shadow rays, so here mainly the surface.
If you had a pure white transparent, it would look like this:

More interestingly, the Principled already have a transparency property (the Alpha), as well as glass (Transmission weight). So you could skip the shader mixing and plug the light path node straight in the Principled, with or without an invert node to invert the effect as desired:

